# How to manage JBoss Wildfly resources(server, applcation etc) in domain mode programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss, wildfly

In JBoss AS in domain mode how can I manage server resources programmatically, that is by my own client app?
That is - to create/remove start/stop servers, server groups, deploy/undeploy applications etc.
I read that this can be achieved by using JMX MBeans. However when running in standalone mode i could list all jboss MBeans, but in domain mode can see only ModuleLoader MBean. Anyway, i found by using JMX MBeans that have to write very long code. So here are the questions:

1) is there a client library for JBoss server resource management for Java?

2) if there is only by JMX to manage resources, then how can i list all MBeans of the server  in domain mode? i put `<remoting-connector/>` in `domain.xml` but should i have to specify anything anywhere else?

The tools i am using are: JBoss Wildfly 8.1, IntelliJ IDEA 13.1, Java 8, Windows 8.1/Debian 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there some reason not to use [JBoss CLI](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CommandLineInterface) for this?

Comment: Hi, you may use the management API in WildFly to manage your domain. This API is available through 'native', REST and the CLI. Look into https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Management+API+reference for more details.